# Writing EsLint plugin for JSX boolean values defaults to true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

In JSX writing something like

```
<JSX someBoolean />
```

Is same as `<JSX someBoolean={true}`
Although according to React this behaviour is just to mimic HTML and should be avoided at code level.
I want to write a linter which enforces the above said rule while writing code.

The problem is that EsLint works on Abstract Syntax Tree(AST).
The flow goes as : JSX gets converted to normal JS which then gets converted to AST.

JSX -> JS -> AST

The default `someBoolean=true` gets supplied to the JS when converting from JSX to JS, so at the AST level I am always getting `someBoolean=true`

So I don't know how can we enforce this rule?

Comment: hi @abhishek, did you find a solution for this ?